# Can I install the new Software Center on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

Can I install the new Software Center that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 on Ubuntu 14.04 using the following?

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

Comment: You can try, but it might not work due to some dependencies error.

Possible duplicate of this: Can I Test the New Gnome Software On Ubuntu 14.04?.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, since it's not present in the 14.04 Ubuntu archive.

To try it you'd need to download the ubuntu-software .deb file together with applicable dependencies and install manually, but you may still encounter unresolvable dependency problems.